# Python does not read file contents in a+ mode. Reads new line character as a separate line between two consecutive lines

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
checkIP = open("checkIP.txt", "r+")
ip = '10.xx.xx.xxx'
checkIP.write(ip)
```

The problem is let say when I write variable ip for first time. It gets added to the file.
Second time when I run the program variable ip is added to file so the file now looks like this.

```
10.xx.xx.xxx10.xx.xx.xxx
```

If instead I have checkIP.write( ip + '\n'), when i run second time the file looks like

```
10.xx.xx.xxx
10.xx.xx.xxx
```

But when I run it third time line by line it reads 10.xx.xx.xxx as first line ,'\n' as second  and 10.xx.xx.xxx as third.

Also if I have a+ as the mode  and after first time I have

```
10.xx.xx.xxx
```

It just reads nothing from file. There is no blank or new line present.

What I want to do is everytime I add an IP it should append in next line and everytime I read there should not be any new line character when I read line by line in python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the full code you're running so we can evaluate your problem.

Comment: are you sure ... this is your code? I ask because `ip = 10.xx.xx.xxx` is not valid python

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes this is the code. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("someText.txt","a+") as f:
     f.writeline(new_ip_address)


ip_addresses = map(str.strip,open("someText.txt"))
```

Im not really sure what your question actually is ... but this will do what you asked for